How to find your solar class space ship that can't be summoned or located when you look under "other ships" on No Mans Sky?
I recently found a ship, in the middle of nowhere, and fixed it up after buying a solar class ship for just over 5 million units.
I took off from the planet and went to the space station, just off planet,; only to realize that the ship I just bought didn't have enough thruster fuel to be summoned.
I also failed to look at the coordinates before leaving. I can't find my recently purchased ship in the "summon" section or under the "other ships" section of the hud either. Without knowing where to find the ship and being unable to summon it..... I fear that it is as good as lost to space.
I've only just started playing No Mans Sky and could really use anyone's help to recover my best ship. Anyone who has started out playing this games knows that resources and units are not something to waste. RIP

Do you own a freighter perhaps? You should find all your ships in its hangar

Related - Is there a way to quickly locate one's own space ship

The weird part is "I can't find the solar class ship I bought under the 'other ships' section of the hud". This almost looks like you exchanged  the solar ship for the one you found instead of "adding the new one to the collection"
